# Avalonia: How to add a Control to UserControl programmatically

Tags: c#, .net-core, avalonia

I can do that on Grid well with `Grid.Children.Add(...)`
But I can't figure out how can I add a control to UserControl programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the `Children` property, your control has to implement the `IPanel` interface. The easiest way to achieve that is to make `Panel` a base class for your `UserControl`.

Comment: I've added a panel to UserControl and used it.